# Flutter Could not resolve all files for configuration

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I was working on a project and is was working fine left it for 6 weeks and tried to run it yesterday and it gave me this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:detachedConfiguration2'.
   > Could not find lint-checks-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/30.1.2/lint-checks-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find lint-api-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/30.1.2/lint-api-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find intellij-core-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.1.2/intellij-core-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find kotlin-compiler-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.1.2/kotlin-compiler-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find uast-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/30.1.2/uast-30.1.2.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried deleting gradle and .gradle folder, also tried using VPN and changed my DNS also tried flutter clean command but non of the above worked.

note1: tried running the project as a windows app and it worked fine so I think its android build related problem.

note2: tried creating a new project and it worked fine.

note3: I have the latest version of flutter and dart.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was solved**

by running `flutter clean` in the project directory
and delete .gradle folder in C:/Users/DESKTOP-NAME/
and finally, `flutter run`.